# What is the difference between estimate and contrasts in SAS?

Tags: self-study, anova, sas

I am having difficulty determining the difference between the two statements.

Answer (score 1):

`estimate` can only test one contrast at a time; `contrast` can test multiple ones simultaneously.  The options for output may also differ slightly, if memory holds.